# Parse string to int when string contains a number + extra characters

Tags: python

Using Python, how can/should I parse a string that has a number, followed by other characters, to an int? The specific problem I am trying to solve is parsing the first number out of a string containing a number followed by an arbitrary amount of other characters, including, possibly other numbers, which I am not interested in.

For example, if the string is `"12//1"`  I need to get just the `12` to an integer.

Comment: -1; I don't mind the simplicity, nor the request for 'Pythonic' answers, but I do mind the poorly specced problem. You've provided a single example string, no use case, and no detailed rules on how you want the parsing to work. Your example doesn't tell us what number you'd want as the result given, for instance, the strings `"//12"`, `" 12//"`, `"1qwerty2"`, `"2.9"`, or `"1 2"`; all the answerers have just guessed at the behavior you want from a single unclear example.

Comment: @MarkAmery  Thanks for the suggestion.  This is a legitimate, albeit simple question for a real problem I was trying to solve, and for which I was unable to find an answer on stack overflow (or google). I apologize for the ambiguity in the original question, and I've updated it to clarify and get rid of the request for "Most pythonic" in exchange for just asking how to do it since that was what I was really after. Feel free to un-1 me, or continue to suggest changes which would lead you to do so, which I will happily take into consideration.

Comment: To the SO police, I've updated my question again to try to make it less terse, including expected results.  As I mentioned  in my previous comment, this is a real world python problem that I wasn't able to find an answer to after a couple of google & SO searches (I'm sure its out there, but if anything, its difficult to get the right words to come up with an accurate result).  Regardless, the answer I ended up going with was immensely useful and SO has served its purpose so feel free to close my question if thats what you're into.

Comment: @djechlin I had the same question. My "research" lead me to this page, which is now the top result on Google!

Comment: @BenRoberts: this question is perfectly legitimate and sadly is just a victim of bad moderation... The problem is IMO also probably quite common but unfortunately apparently not solved reasonably by the standard Python library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use this regular expression:

```
import re
try:
    print int(re.compile("(\d+)").match('12//').group(1))
except:
    print "there was no number"
```

It will extract all digits and stops at the first non-digit character.

`\d` means single digit, `\d+` means match at least one digit and `(\d+)` together means return what have you found in group 1.

Comment: +1 for regular expressions :D

Comment: It also bails out before checking the entire string (in case there's one digit and one million slashes...)

Comment: *facepalm* that the Pythonic way to do things is by throwing regexes at them.

Comment: You don't need a capture group here; you can use `"\d+"` and use `.group()` with no arguments.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to extract the digits in the string:

```
int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()))
```

Comment: +1 for the pythonic way

Comment: I wish Python supported `(c for c in s while c.isdigit())`...

Comment: @arshajii ahh, now your answer looks nice again :-) `lambda` is so 1999...

Comment: @OmriBarel Actually there's no need for the `lambda` (see the update). In my opinion `takewhile` is the best approach here.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like a job for [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> s = '12//'
>>> int(''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit, s)))
12
```

Comment: this only works assuming you start with a digit, otherwise it will throw a ValueError

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a cool technique, but it may be overkill for just this if it's only the format you describe:

```
import string
potential_bad_characters = string.ascii_puctuation + string.ascii_letters

int(my_string.translate(None,potential_bad_characters ))

#Or
int(mystring.rstrip(potential_bad_characters))

#Or
int(filter(str.isdigit,my_string))

#Or (kudos @JonClements)
potential_bad_characters = ''.join(map(chr, range(256))).replace('0123456789', '')
...
```

Comment: Instead of "potential", you could invert the "allowed", eg: `''.join(map(chr, range(256))).replace('0123456789', '')` (is one way)

Comment: I would love the filter solution, if a `filter` didn't return an iterator which is an unacceptable input for `int()`. At least in python 3.8, you wind up having to use join here as well. Compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340058/how-to-convert-instance-of-class-filter-to-str-directly)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to jh314s solution, but only takes digits before any non-digit character (so 34//98 would become 34, not 3498). Assume string is "s":

```
nonDigitIdx = [idx for idx,ch in enumerate(s) if not ch.isdigit()][0]
i = int(s[:nonDigitIdx-1])
```