# how to convert instance of class "filter" to str directly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
url = 'https://www.shanbay.com/read/article/97936/' 
temp = filter(str.isdigit,url)    #slect numbers
```

Instead of using `for...in expression`, can I convert `temp` to `str` directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter`s are lazy in Python 3, you'll need to feed them to a function that will consume them and force them to produce their elements.

```
url = 'https://www.shanbay.com/read/article/97936/' 
temp = filter(str.isdigit,url)  # filter object
```

If you feed this to another function that consumes it, you can get back the elements. If you need a string, just `join` it:

```
nums = "".join(temp)
```

`"".join` will get all the elements from the `filter` instance and join them on the empty string `""` producing `97936`; use that in an `int` call if you require an `int` result.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` returns an iterator, so you'd have to join its elements.

```
url = 'https://www.shanbay.com/read/article/97936/' 
temp = "".join(filter(str.isdigit,url))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `re.findall()`?

```
import re
url = 'https://www.shanbay.com/read/article/97936/'
temp = re.findall('[0-9]+', url)
```

Comment: It also returns an array, so you'll have to make the `"".join()` trick anyway